# Servlet not opening the welcome page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to create a simple login page using JSP and servlets.
When I click on the login button after entering admin and admin, it gives me an error 404 and does not open the success.jsp page.

The code for login.jsp and LoginController.java(servlet) is below. Please help me.

PS: I am using a mac and eclipse IDE.

login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="LoginController" method="post">
Enter username :<input type="text" name="username"> <br>
Enter password :<input type="password" name="password"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

LoginController.java

```
            import java.io.IOException;
            import javax.servlet.ServletException;
            import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
            import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
            import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
            /**
             * Servlet implementation class LoginController
             */
            public class LoginController extends HttpServlet {

                protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                    String un=request.getParameter("username");
                    String pw=request.getParameter("password");

                    if(un.equals("admin") && pw.equals("admin"))
                    {
                        response.sendRedirect("success.jsp");
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response.sendRedirect("error.html");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
      <display-name>Login</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

Comment: Can you please provide `web.xml` ?

Comment: What URL you see when you get the error?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/Login/LoginController

@Pshemo

Comment: Where is `success.jsp`?

Comment: You can't invoke servlet methods just by using its name. One servlet can handle many URLs, but you need to set that mapping either in web.xml or via annotations. I don't see any of such mappings in your code which is why you can't access it.

Comment: It is placed in web-contents folder. @HardikModha

Comment: How do we map it? @Pshemo

Comment: Mapping for `LoginController` is missing in `web.xml`.

Comment: Take a look at examples in duplicate question (you may need to refresh this page to see link at top of your question).